# Why is the address space of a 32-bit processor 4Gibibytes and not 4Gibibits?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture

> A 32-bit register can store 2<sup>32</sup> different values. The signed range of
>   integer values that can be stored in 32 bits is -2,147,483,648 through
>   2,147,483,647 (unsigned: 0 through 4,294,967,295). Hence, a processor
>   with 32-bit memory addresses can directly access 4 GiB of
>   byte-addressable memory.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit

What confuses me is that we are talking about a 32-**bit** processor which can address 2<sup>32</sup> different addresses. But now 2<sup>32</sup> is in bytes and not bits, why is that?

Comment: Because you can't typically address anything smaller than a byte in memory. If you need a particular bit, read a byte/halfword/word/whatever, and extract the bit you need using bitwise logic.

Comment: @Michael: Post that as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest addressable unit in memory is a byte (exceptions to this rule exist, but you were asking about x86 specifically). So if your addresses are N-bit, you can represent 2^N different addresses, which means that you can address 2^N individual bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Each unique address points to a byte of memory in the address map, and not a bit. In other words, memory is byte addressable that's why 32bits can address 4GBytes.